# Webpage has expired error in IE, only happens over HTTPS

Tags: internet-explorer

I have seen numerous posts about the IE "Webpage has expired" error message, but none that seem to address my case. I have a site that can run over HTTP or HTTPS. One of the pages has a button that does the equivalent of clicking "Back" through javascript. This returns to a page where there was a form POST. The problem I have is that it works fine when viewing the page over HTTP. I only get the "Webpage has expired" message when running over HTPS. Is there any way to make it work over HTTPS, whether it be through code or just changing IE browser settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into the POST Redirect GET design pattern where a POST is only used for sending data to the db or to the server for processing, and all data displayed comes from a GET that the POST calls.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that solution, but I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to minimize changes if at all possible. Figured it might be doable since it works fine over regular HTTP.